# std::sort equal objects with multiple properties

Tags: c++, sorting, std

I'm trying to sort a vector of objects so that objects with the same properties are right next to each other. `Task` is a class that takes and holds 3 pointers to some data somewhere.

```
vec.push_back(Task(&propertyOne, &propertyTwo, &propertyThree));
```

If I have a vector full of these, I want to sort them so that any `Task` that has equal `propertyOne`, `propertyTwo`, and `propertyThree` are put next to each other in the vector. If the two `Task` objects properties are not equal, it doesn't really matter where they go. Although it would be nice for them to go next to the `Task` objects that they have the most in common with.

How do I do this? I've tried the obvious (`return a.propertyOne == b.propertyOne`) but that didn't seem to work at all, and also it only compares the first property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best solution is use a [`tuple<property*, property*, property*>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) not a `Task`. This comes with [comparison operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp) defined so you could simply do: `vec.push_back(make_tuple(&propertyOne, &propertyTwo, &propertyThree))` for each entry into `vec`, then to sort just do:

```
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end())
```

If `Task` must be more elaborate than a `tuple<property*, property*, property*>`, you should define comparison operators for `Task`:

```
bool Task::operator< (const Task& rhs) {
    return make_tuple(a, b, c) < make_tuple(rhs.a, rhs.b, rhs.c);
}

bool Task::operator== (const Task& rhs) {
    return a == rhs.a && b == rhs.b && c == rhs.c;
}
```

Once these two are defined you can again do:

```
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end())
```

Comment: This looks about right, but a, b, and c are class objects (in this case, pointers to class objects). Can I still use the < operator?

Comment: @Dooskington Depends on how you're comparing them. If you want the objects themselves to be compared you'll need to dereference the pointers. (If that's what you want you really need to edit your question, and then I'll edit my answer.) My checks are comparing the location the objects are stored in memory. Given: `auto a = new string, b = new string;` `a` will not equal `b`, but `*a` will equal `*b`. Does that make sense? Are you trying to compare object properties here or just the memory location?

Comment: Just the memory location. To be more specific, I am sorting a queue of RenderCommand objects and each RenderCommand has a Texture*, Material*, and PrimitiveType(which is an enum class). So basically if the Texture pointers point to the same Texture, the Material pointers point to the same material, and the PrimativeType equals the other PrimativeType, then the RenderCommands should be next to each other in the queue. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Dooskington That does make sense, directly comparing pointers in is common in C++. Like when you iterate over an array, it's the position in the array relative to the end position that matters. This answer will sort similarly. Allocations made at lower addresses will appear first in the sorted `vec`. This is without respect to object contents. So even if two object contain identical data, they will not sort together in the array, only objects that point to the *same object* will sore together. Unless you've implemented [object interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).

Comment: @Morwenn Thanks. It turns out you do need some ability in the spelling area to be a programmer.

Comment: By the way, can't you simply use `std::tie` to implement the  custom comparisons? :)

Comment: @Morwenn I feel like I might be about to learn something. In the first option if `Task` is replaced by a `tuple<property*, property*, property*>` I don't think there is a need for `tie`, as the comparison operators are already defined. Perhaps you're suggesting using `tie` in `Task::operator<` or `Task::operator==`? I don't see how that would be helpful, can you enlighten me?

Comment: `bool Task::operator< (const Task& rhs) { return std::tie(a, b, c) < std::tie(rhs.a, rhs.b, rhs.c); }` is what I was talking about.

Comment: @Morwenn Ah, I didn't know that you could use `tie` like that. I had considered using `make_tuple` to the same end, but I finally decided that it added extra overhead to construct those `tuple`s and then do the exact comparison that I was already gonna do. But I could be persuaded `make_tuple`/`tie` was better if you had an argument toward that side?

Comment: I don't have any specific argument, just general things: it's terser, easy to visually parse (and to understand once you know how it works), and less error-prone since there is less code to type and it's hard to get it wrong. I guess that the tuple construction may be elided by the compiler to simply perform the comparison, but I would have to look at the generated assembly in order to assert that (but it's a tuple of references, so no copies are needed anyway).

Comment: @Morwenn The more I think about this the more I agree with you. I'm gonna choose to believe that the compiler will clean this up, cause the code is cleaner this way. With 3 variables I can write it out, but am I honestly gonna write it out with 10 variables? So if nothing else for consistency between the 3 and 10 variable cases I agree with you. I've edited my answer. That said, I don't think this is advantageous in the equality operator, so I've left that one alone.

Answer (score 3):

Let's task have three properties a, b, c for short. To sort such tasks in correct order you have to do something like this:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const Task& l, const Task& r) {
  if (l.a == r.a) {
    if (l.b == r.b) {
      return l.c < r.c;
    }
    return l.b < r.b;
  }
  return l.a < r.a;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it using a simple lambda containing a couple of ternary operators

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const Task& l, const Task& r)
  {
      return (l.a == r.a) ?
          ((l.b == r.b) ? (l.c < r.c) : (l.b < r.b)) :
          (l.a < r.a);
  });
```

This obviously assumes the properties `a` and `b` can be compared using `==`, and that all three properties can be compared using `<`.

Alternatively, you might want to supply appropriate specialisations of functionals from `<functional>` (`std::equal_to`, `std::less`, etc) and use those instead.